# PHP coding in real world !!! do I need to learn any Framework?

Tags: php

I know how to write program in PHP and implementation of MVC model. but I really want to practice coding like the coding in real world??? I was wondering is there any specific example or book which can show me the tricks or logic and the way professional programmers consider about coding??? Do I need to learn frameworks like Zend ???

Comment: You should make a large website!!! And read Code Complete!!!!! http://cc2e.com/

Comment: Yes, this is a good way to learn how to code in the real world :)
For example: write a portal, or a blog engine, with lots of stuff. Imagine and create. You can create nearly everything you want, just try it ;)

Comment: Develop a framework for others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way I consider and used for my own learning is to see the **[best sites out there](http://www.hotscripts.com/category/php/scripts-programs/top-sites/)** and try to create a **clone** of them. This is really real-world way you can go with PHP development.

Another great path is to **[involve yourself in open source projects](https://openhatch.org/)**.

> Do I need to learn frameworks like
>   Zend ???

It will be a nightmare if you have no idea of what **[OOP](http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php/)** is (and/or MVC architecture), if you have good understanding of OOP, you can dive into it, it is great practical learning there with it too.

Comment: Almost a -1 for cloning a site. It is far better/rewarding to do something original.

Comment: Open source projects aren't necessarily the best thing. Especially not for beginners. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/04/is-open-source-experience-overrated.html

Comment: @Byron: Do everyone has necessarily to agree to what the author of coding horror says? I don't think so all will say yes to it. Some may favor it other may not.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say get involved in an open source project. You'll be dealing with larger teams, source control, documentation, QA, and bugs (to name a few). The timelines aren't always as quick or rigid as the corporate world but it's similar (IMHO).

Answer (score 3):

> but I really want to practice coding like the coding in real world?

Just get a job or do some freelancing for clients or pick a personal project, develop and publish it. It's hard to learn 'real world' coding through books.

P.S. I like books and blogs and all that. But they only take you so far. Just get your hands 'dirty' ..

Comment: Good point about getting one's hands dirty on a real project. But I'd focus more on a personal project or helping an open source project. ie a project where mistakes only affect the programmer, or a project where senior developers moderate the code.  If you hire out to a client, the client is not expecting to fund your learning curve. The inevitable noob errors will adversely affect future contracts.

Comment: Yes, a job maybe too much. But a small freelance project will give you some valueable incentives: a) real code and code that's used b) deadlines c) insights into collaboration ...